# How to output a Multiline Character Image in the console

Tags: java, string, ascii, java-text-blocks

I am developing a text-based game and I want to make the title something catchy. I tried to use a text to ASCII converter to make a nice-looking title and then copy and paste it in my code to output it, but it didn't work.

Here is what I tried to do:

```java
System.out.println("
██████╗ ██╗   ██╗███╗   ██╗ ██████╗ ███████╗ ██████╗ ███╗   ██╗     ██████╗ ███████╗                            
██╔══██╗██║   ██║████╗  ██║██╔════╝ ██╔════╝██╔═══██╗████╗  ██║    ██╔═══██╗██╔════╝                            
██║  ██║██║   ██║██╔██╗ ██║██║  ███╗█████╗  ██║   ██║██╔██╗ ██║    ██║   ██║█████╗                              
██║  ██║██║   ██║██║╚██╗██║██║   ██║██╔══╝  ██║   ██║██║╚██╗██║    ██║   ██║██╔══╝                              
██████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║ ╚████║╚██████╔╝███████╗╚██████╔╝██║ ╚████║    ╚██████╔╝██║                                 
╚═════╝  ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═══╝ ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═══╝     ╚═════╝ ╚═╝                                 
                                                                                                                
    ████████╗██╗  ██╗███████╗    ███████╗ ██████╗ ██████╗  ██████╗  ██████╗ ████████╗████████╗███████╗███╗   ██╗
    ╚══██╔══╝██║  ██║██╔════╝    ██╔════╝██╔═══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝ ██╔═══██╗╚══██╔══╝╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝████╗  ██║
       ██║   ███████║█████╗      █████╗  ██║   ██║██████╔╝██║  ███╗██║   ██║   ██║      ██║   █████╗  ██╔██╗ ██║
       ██║   ██╔══██║██╔══╝      ██╔══╝  ██║   ██║██╔══██╗██║   ██║██║   ██║   ██║      ██║   ██╔══╝  ██║╚██╗██║
       ██║   ██║  ██║███████╗    ██║     ╚██████╔╝██║  ██║╚██████╔╝╚██████╔╝   ██║      ██║   ███████╗██║ ╚████║
       ╚═╝   ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝    ╚═╝      ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝  ╚═════╝    ╚═╝      ╚═╝   ╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝");
```

But it didn't seem to work. I know it works in JavaScript, but I was wondering if it would also work in Java.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your console cannot support those characters. For instance, I wouldn't fancy your chances at all if you were running Windows. If you are, Powershell might be more hopeful than cmd.exe

Comment: To me it looks like it's working, but the spacing or line feed is incorrect

Comment: I think it will be tricky to include that in your source. I'd be inclined to load a UTF-8 file containing the string such as [THIS](http://technojeeves.com/tech/the-forgotten.txt.gz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### String literals

[String literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) - is a string consists of zero or more characters enclosed in double quotes `"myText"`.

It is not possible to create a multiline string literal in Java, precisely as you've tried it. According to the language specification it's a compile-time error, line termination is present in a string lateral.

```
String invalidLiteral = "line1
                         line2
                         ..."; // will cause a compilation error
```

To make such string literal compile, line termination can be replaced with a new line character `\n`.

```
String validString = "line1\nline2\nline3";
```

The resulting string can become very long, in order to make it readable you can split the string into chunks concatenated with a plus sign `+`, appending a new line character `\n` to each chunk.

```
String validConcatinatedString = "line1\n" +
                                 "line2\n" +
                                 "line3";
```

Although it'll work, it might be tedious.

#### Text Blocks

With Java 15 you can create a multiline string using [text blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) available.

In order to create a text block, you need to enclose the target multiline text in triple double-quote characters `"""`.

```
String myASCIIArt = """ // no text after the opening delimiter
              Your amazing 
                  ASCII art 
                       here""";
```

**Note** that the opening delimiter `"""` should be *immediately* followed by the *line termination*, and the actual body of the text block always starts on the next line.